# iterate through span id's passing id as value to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iteration

Supposing I have a table that has been dynamically generated with one of the columns having a unique span id:

```
<tr><td><span id="123"></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="124"></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="125"></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="126"></span></td></tr>
```

What is the best way to iterate through the spans with a javascript function so that the span id can be passed as a value that the function can then use?

Comment: If the `<span>` elements all shared a common class, it'd be really easy.

Comment: that can be done - what do you suggest

Comment: `$("td > span").each(function() { var id = this.id; });`!

Comment: So you're trying to turn the spans into an array that you can iterate through?

Comment: there has to be parent element so that we can traverse through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the jQuery `each` function](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over your `span`s and do something with their `id` property:

```js
$('#table-id span').each(handleElement)

function handleElement () {
  var id = this.id
  // Do something with `id`
  console.log(id)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-id">
  <tr><td><span id="123"></span></td></tr>
  <tr><td><span id="124"></span></td></tr>
  <tr><td><span id="125"></span></td></tr>
  <tr><td><span id="126"></span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign a same class to each of the span items and then make use of [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and iterate through the array.

```
var targetElements = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
```

**Update (with jQuery)**

You may be able to use iterate through this using the following code as well.

```
jQuery('table td > span').each(function() {
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    // Your logic
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the jquery loop construct to loop through the table data.

   $("tr td").each(function() {
       var foo = $(this).find("span").attr('id');
   });